# Can someone explain this input of array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code, what is this input of arrays? I just want to know more about the input in this code

```cpp
int n;

   float c[10][3];

cout<<“Enter the number of vertices :”;

cin>>n;

        for (i=0;i<n;i++)



{ 

 cout<<“Enter the coordinates of the vertex :”,i+1;.   

   cin>>c[i][0]>>c[i][1];

 c[i][2]=1

  }
```

Comment: What exactly do you need explained? :)

Comment: I wanna know how did this code take input in array the bestest u can explain me

Answer (score 0):

You are taking values in this form

Array C

```
x  y  1
x1 y1 1
.
.
.
x9 y9 1
```

Basically your i iterates through all the rows of an 2 dimensional array and taken 2 inputs for 1st and 2nd location respectively. 3rd location is always set as 1.

Comment: Nd when user input in N then the array size changes right?  Eg it's 10 by default user enter 3 now it will loop till 3 rows

Comment: Sorry. The arrray size doesnt change. Number of iterations will change.You should validate that n<10 always. Otherwise there will be segfault.